# Export hair data from Blender

Tags: export, hair

I'm blocked by retrieving hair data from Blender. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some suggestions on what I should do.

```
# first way to export data
transform = obj.matrix_world.inverted()
num_parents = len(ps.particles)
num_children = len(ps.child_particles)
for pindex in range(num_parents + num_children):
    for step in range(0, hair_step + 1):
        co = transform * ps.co_hair(obj, pindex, step)
        verts += POINTFMT.pack( co[0] , co[1] , co[2] )

# second way to export data
for i, h in enumerate(ps.particles):
    for i, hv in enumerate(h.hair_keys):
        verts += POINTFMT.pack( hv.co[0] , hv.co[1] , hv.co[2] )
```

And each of them has its own problem. The first one seems to export wrong data somehow, it doesn't give me correct data. The second solution works well, but it has another problem, there is no support for ChildParticles, but the data is correct.

And both of them are very very slow, is there any way to make it faster?
I noticed that the internal feature of converting the particles to mesh works surprisingly fast, is it implemented in python?

Thanks